# Cast anonymous function argument

Tags: typescript

I can't seem to find any clear instruction on how to cast an argument to an anonymous function. I can cast on variable assignment, just not sure if this is possible and how.

Since I'm using lodash the typings define the argument as `any` but I need to cast it to a custom object, since in reality it would be.

```
_.findLast(this.children, function((CustomObject) node) {
  node.customMethod();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
_.findLast(this.children, function(node: any) {
  var co = <CustomObject> node;
  co.customMethod();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for something that didn't require a new line but at least I have a solution. This doesn't seem to work as written, I can't overwrite the `node` variable since it's already used, but using any other variable name works.

Comment: By blind luck, it seems that `return (<TreeNode> node).visible();` works

Answer (score 1):

Blind luck led me to discover that `(<CustomObject> node).customMethod();` works.

Comment: You should accept @DAXaholic's answer. This answer is his in one line.

Comment: a answer should be selected, whichever it may be :) and yes a like in Wayne's World